# How to click on text in html using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have got district names like these : Anantapur, Chittoor etc.. I have 13 districts. I have to click on each district. This is how HTML looks like:

```
</tr>
<tr class="gridRowStyle" align="center" style="color:#000066;">
    <td>
                                        1
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lnkbtnDist" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Grid_Dist$ctl02$lnkbtnDist','')">Anantapur</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lblDman">63</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lblMvill">2856</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lblMcon">215441</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lblDNExist">49681</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lblDExist">165760</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lblMupcon">215437</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl02_lblPer">100.00</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlterRowStyle" align="center" style="color:#000066;">
    <td>
                                        2
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl03_lnkbtnDist" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Grid_Dist$ctl03$lnkbtnDist','')">Chittoor</a>
```

I have tried Selenium to click on the text but somehow I am not able to do that.

**Python**

```
a=[2,14]
for i in a:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist']//tr[i]//td[2]").click()
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

I need to click on the text Anantapur, Chittoor etc.. But it is not working. FYI: This is the website: http://65.19.149.160/gws/reports.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Consider using a more clear XPath locator as these `//tr[i]//td[2]` are not readable and very fragile, in case of minimal [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) change the locators will become invalid. I would recommend sticking to partial [`id` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) like:

   ```
   //a[contains(@id,'lnkbtnDist')]
   ```

   Check out the following material to master XPath:

   - [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
   - [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
   - [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)
2. Once you navigate away from the page and come back all [WebElements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) will be invalidated and you will have to find them once again. To avoid this you can use [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and convert the list of WebElements to the list of strings (district names)

   ```
   districts = [link.text for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@id,'lnkbtnDist')]")]
   ```
3. Assuming all above you can amend your code to look like:

   ```
   driver.get("http://65.19.149.160/gws/reports.aspx")

   districts = [link.text for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@id,'lnkbtnDist')]")]

   for district in districts:
       driver.find_element_by_link_text(district).click()
       driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of more information about where exactly you are stuck would have helped us to answer the question in a better way. However the desired elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  base_url = "http://65.19.149.160/gws/reports.aspx"
  driver.get(base_url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Anantapur"))).click()
  print("Data from Anantapur district")
  driver.get(base_url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Chittoor"))).click()
  print("Data from Chittoor district")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Data from Anantapur district
  Data from Chittoor district
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To click on Each `District` name 
First you need to get the count of the total district available on the web table and then `iterate` each district and click.Once click on link it `navigates` to a `new page` so you need to use `driver.back()` to return to initial page and go on.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://65.19.149.160/gws/reports.aspx")

Districts=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist']//a[contains(@id,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl')]")))

for d in range(len(Districts)):
  Districts = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist']//a[contains(@id,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Grid_Dist_ctl')]")))
  print("District Name clicked :" + Districts[d].text)
  Districts[d].click()
  driver.back()
```

Output On Console:

```
District Name clicked :Anantapur
District Name clicked :Chittoor
District Name clicked :East Godavari
District Name clicked :Guntur
District Name clicked :Kadapa
District Name clicked :Krishna
District Name clicked :Kurnool
District Name clicked :Nellore
District Name clicked :Prakasam
District Name clicked :Srikakulam
District Name clicked :Visakhapatnam
District Name clicked :Vizianagaram
District Name clicked :West Godavari
```

Comment: Thanks you! Though I have used Dmitri's solution, I want to mention that your solution is also working perfectly.